# jqte text editor is changing html tags

Tags: html, text-editor, jqte

I am using [jqte](http://jqueryte.com) as a text editor with my CodeIgniter application however when I save the content it's converting the tags which I don't want it to do.

For example, I would like it like this:

```
<p>Lorum ipsum<br />dolor simit</p>
```

but instead it is changing to this:

```
&lt;p&gt;Lorum ipsum&lt;br&gt;dolor simit&lt;p&gt;
```

How do I convert it back?

Comment: Are you sure that is jqte that is decoding the html tags? Isn't your server-side?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's not jqte, it's something in CI

Answer (score 1):

In php you can use

```
<?php
 echo htmlspecialchars_decode($your_string);
?>
```